# function that returns a pointer; In C

Tags: c

I imagine this to be a relatively simple answer.  I am just getting used to pointers and I am just about done however I cannot figure out this error:

> PtrBasicBCGold.cc:27:13: error: no matching function for call to
>   'HelperFunc'    maxPtr = HelperFunc(&i1, &i2, &i3, &i4);
>               ^~~~~~~~~~ PtrBasicBCGold.cc:3:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int **' to  'int *' for 1st
>   argument; remove &   int *HelperFunc(int *i1, int *i2, int *i3, int
>   *i4)
>        ^ 1 error generated.

The prompt is to keep the below setup of an increment function and a helper.  But I cannot figure out how to return the pointer without an error of this sort.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *HelperFunc(int *i1, int *i2, int *i3, int *i4)
{

   if(*i1 > *i2 && *i1 > *i3 && *i1 > *i4)
   {
       return i1;
   }
      if(*i2 > *i1 && *i2 > *i3 && *i2 > *i4)
   {
      return i2;
   }
   if(*i3 > *i1 && *i3 > *i2 && *i3 > *i4)
   {
      return i3;
   }
   else return i4;
}

void IncrementMax(int *i1, int *i2, int *i3, int *i4)
{
   int *maxPtr;
   maxPtr = HelperFunc(&i1, &i2, &i3, &i4);
   *maxPtr = *maxPtr + 1;
}


int main() {
   int i1, i2, i3, i4;

   scanf("%d %d %d %d", &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4);

   IncrementMax(&i1, &i2, &i3, &i4);

   printf("%d %d %d %d", i1, i2, i3, i4);

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: That's apparently not C, but C++. Don't spam, tags!

Comment: @Olaf why do you suggest this is C++ but not C? I don't see any C++ here

Comment: except perhaps the function name style, the rest is simply C

Comment: "PtrBasicBCGold.**cc**" Invokes the C++ compiler. and you apparently use a C++ compiler judging from the error message. Thus it is not C! Identical syntax/grammar does not imply identical semantics. If you want C, you have to use a C compiler. (Note: you really would better use C for this)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

`maxPtr = HelperFunc(&i1, &i2, &i3, &i4);`

You function call does not match with your prototype. Note that `i1`, `i2`, etc. are already pointers, so you do not need `&` which is the address of. If you do so it would be pointer to pointer to int, which is not what you need.

This change should fix the issue:

`maxPtr = HelperFunc(i1, i2, i3, i4);`

Comment: Oh of course, thank you!